# Microsoft Graph Filter not filtering correct

Tags: c#, filter, microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Im using C# to get messages from a mailbox. For some unknown reasons, I only can read 11 Messages at once. But this isn't a problem. So I decided to save the recievedDateTime of the last message to start reading new messages later (when executing the next time).

```
DateTime lastrun = DateTime.Parse(File.ReadAllText("lastrun.txt"));
try {  
  var messages = await graphServiceClient.Users["***User***"].Messages.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) => {
    string filter = "ReceivedDateTime ge " + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz}", lastrun);
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = filter;
  });
  foreach (var message in messages.Value) {
    // do my stuff
    if (lastrun < message.ReceivedDateTime) {
      lastrun = message.ReceivedDateTime.Value.DateTime;
    }
  }
} catch (Exception ex) {
  throw;
}
```

I then save the DateTime.

```
File.WriteAllText("lastrun.txt",lastrun.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz"));
```

In my example the first Message is recieved at "2024-02-12T07:10:31+01:00"

The last Mail is recieved at "2024-02-12T07:16:56+01:00"

I then start the program and following filter is used:

```
receivedDateTime ge 2024-02-12T07:16:56+01:00
```

My method continues to read the same messages again and saves the same "enddate" again.
Why is Microsoft reading messages, which are recieved before the date of the filter? Do I have some problems with different timezones?

Comment: Let's read the [API document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), `Depending on the page size and mailbox data, getting messages from a mailbox can incur multiple requests. The default page size is 10 messages. Use $top to customize the page size, within the range of 1 and 1000.` and `To get the next page of messages, simply apply the entire URL returned in @odata.nextLink to the next get-messages request. This URL includes any query parameters you may have specified in the initial request.` I think this can answer your question

Comment: and I had a test before with Graph SDK v4.x: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72081881/14574199

Comment: By default, the Graph API returns only 10 messages. You can specify the number of items to be returned in $top query parameter => QueryParameters.Top = 100. The second option is to use page iterator: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#pageiterator. Not sure how the messages are ordered, but it can be the root cause, try to order messages: QueryParameters.Orderby = new string []{ "receivedDateTime desc" };

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me how to get more than 10 Messages. But this didn't answer my question, why the filter is reading messages from the past.

Comment: Hi @JensKörte Thank you for your reply. `why the filter is reading messages from the past` -> according to your description -->`My method continues to read the same messages again and saves the same "enddate" again` which looks like the filter didn't work at all right? Then let's see the [property details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) for Message, we can see there's no description to say this property is supporting filter for `receivedDateTime`.

Comment: As a comparison for [properties of User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), we can see properties like `accountEnabled ageGroup businessPhones` etc are supporting filter. Therefore, you are using an invalid filter in the query which causing the issue.

Comment: @TinyWang I see your point but the filter is working somehow, though it is not "supported". When I change the date manually, I recieve the correct mails. It seems that my program isn't at the right timezone and therefore the recievedDateTime is "wrong"

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Can we call it's a case now?

Answer (score 2):

This is not due to "filter not working", but by design for the [list message API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). When we call this API, it would return 10 items by default.

> The default page size is 10 messages. Use $top to customize the page
> size, within the range of 1 and 1000.

So that we need to use `PageIterator` to list all the messages. If we are calling the api via http request, then we can follow the API document to use `@odata.nextLink` to send following-up requests for the rest of the messages, if we are using Graph SDK, we can follow the [offcial document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp#iterate-over-all-the-messages) to use `PageIterator` for listing all message. We don't need to store the date and start another query. Below is the sample code from document.

```
var messages = await graphClient.Me.Messages
    .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
    {
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 10;
        requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select =
            ["sender", "subject", "body"];
        requestConfiguration.Headers.Add(
            "Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"");
    });

if (messages == null)
{
    return;
}

var pageIterator = PageIterator<Message, MessageCollectionResponse>
    .CreatePageIterator(
        graphClient,
        messages,
        // Callback executed for each item in
        // the collection
        (msg) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Subject);
            return true;
        },
        // Used to configure subsequent page
        // requests
        (req) =>
        {
            // Re-add the header to subsequent requests
            req.Headers.Add("Prefer", "outlook.body-content-type=\"text\"");
            return req;
        });

await pageIterator.IterateAsync();
```